# Is there a Javascript event for constantly updating the DOM based on user input?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm fairly new to JS, and I plan on learning some PHP soon.

So I have a set of three select boxes: the chapter of a book, the start page, and the end page.  Whenever the user selects a chapter, I want the other two select boxes to update appropriately (from page 1 to the length of that specific chapter).  I was able to do this with the following (I will eventually replace the if statements with a case block):

```
var chapter = $("#chapter option:selected").val();
if (chapter == 1)
{
    $('#page_start').empty();
    $('#page_end').empty();
    var n = 7;
    for (var i=1; i<=n; i++)
    {
        var o = new Option(i, i);
        $("#page_start").append(o);
        var p = new Option(i, i);
        $("#page_end").append(p);
    }
}
```

But my problem is that this code will only execute if the user selects Chapter 1, and then refreshes the page.  I want the user to be able to see changes immediately upon his/her selection.  Is there a Javascript event that will enable me to do this?  I tried enclosing the above codeblock in a document.ready event, but with no success.

Do you have any tips?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to detect user input, try the `input` event…

Comment: Need the HTML and script in a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap it in an event, which in this case would most likely be `change`. This particular code will execute when `#chapter` changes:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $pageStart = $('#page_start');
    $pageEnd = $('#page_end');

    $("#chapter").on('change', function() {

        var chapter = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
        if (chapter == 1)
        {

            $pageStart.empty();
            $pageEnd.empty();
            var n = 7;
            for (var i=1; i<=n; i++)
            {
                var o = new Option(i, i);
                $pageStart.append(o);
                var p = new Option(i, i);
                $pageEnd.append(p);
            }
        }

    });

});
```

Assuming your code is in the `<head>`, you'll need to wrap it in a `$(document).ready( function () { ... } );` as I have above. This is to ensure that the element we're applying the listener to (`#chapter`) is loaded, and will be found when we try to reference it.

You'll also notice that I've set your `#page_start` and `#page_end` elements to variables. This is because each time you do `$('#page_start')`, you're traversing the DOM to find the element. By setting it to a variable once, you save your code a substantial workload by not having to repeatedly search for the same element.